# android.support.v7 Toolbar & DrawerLayout- how to hide Hamburger icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-toolbar, drawertoggle

I am implementing Toolbar along and Navigation drawer.I am customized my tool bar with my own views.I have my own menu(Hamburger) icon in my toolbar to open navigation drawer and I am showing badge count on my menu icon(Hamburger).So i would like to hide default Hamburger icon.

I have tried like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us more code please

Comment: A screenshot of your toolbar too please

Answer (score 18):

call `.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` on your ActionBarDrawerToggle

Comment: I use a toolbar then I don't have a actionbardrawertoggle instance so how can I do it then? Any idea?

Comment: @user1007522 use can get actionBarToggle instance this way: toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
public void setLogo(String imageUrl) {
  ViewGroup toolbarView = (ViewGroup) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

  // set an arbitrary logo so the support library adds an ImageView to the toolbar.
  // without this, there would be no ImageView elements in the toolbar
  // and the following loop would not work
  // `empty_drawable` is a simple rectangle of size 100x100 with a bg color
  // matching that of the toolbar
  // the size really matters because the smaller you set this image, the next logo
  // you set will be of that size. If your arbitrary drawable is of size 1x1, then
  // the next logo you set will be of the same size. At least that is what happens
  // for me when I load an image with Glide.
  // Your drawable should have a background color too. I chose the toolbar's
  // background color. If you don't set a background color, your app would crash on Kitkat.
  toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.empty_drawable);

  for (int i = 0; i < toolbarView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if ((toolbarView.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageView)) {
      ImageView logoView = (ImageView) toolbarView.getChildAt(i);

      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        // this way I can download an image and set the logo that way
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageUrl).into(logoView);

        // I do this because there is no space between logo and the toolbar title
        logoView.setPadding(0, 0, 30, 0);

        // and this is because of the `else` block
        logoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
        // pass null to `setLogo()` to hide the logo
        logoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        logoView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
  app:title="@string/app_name"
  tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

The `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` part makes all this really nice.
And `tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"` is because my app's minimum SDK is set to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity's onCreate:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(
   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

If you're using the AppCompat, replace `getActionBar` with `getSupportActionBar`.